# Fish 'bind' with Ctrl+Alt and ArrowUp

Tags: macos, shell, bind, fish, modifier-key

On a Fish 2.0.0 shell I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowUp</kbd> with some command. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it:

`bind \c\earrow-up 'touch /tmp/it_worked'`

I believe I have two problems, one the combination between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the other that I don't know how to define the arrow up sequence.

Actually I tried something less convoluted with the `[` key:
`bind \c\[ 'touch /tmp/it_worked'`

But that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.7.

**update:** There is a bug for that: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1024

Comment: The linked issue seems to be closed as resolved, yet I'm still unable to rebind Alt+Up...

Comment: Oooh, the problem was that I was using `bind "\e\[1\;3A"` (with **quotes**), which didn't overwrite the preset `bind \e\[1\;3A` (without quotes)